# How do I get values of same indexes from multiple arrays using numpy?

Tags: python-3.x, numpy

```
a = np.array([ 0.1, 0.2, 0.4, 0.5, 0.9])
b = np.array([ 1.2, 1.5, 1.7, 2.0, 2.4])
c = np.array([ 4.1, 5.3, 5.1, 5.0, 3.2])
```

First, I have to find the elements where `c >= 5` so I typed:

```
threshold = np.where( c >= 5 )
```

I then have to find the elements of `a` and `b` in the same index where `c` is the lowest value within that threshold. As we can see the lowest is `c = 5.0` in this example so it should show me:

```
a = 0.5
b = 2.0
c = 5.0
```

I have no idea how to do so, please help me! Thanks.

Comment: Did the posted solution work for you?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's one way -

```
# Get thresholded indices
In [97]: threshold = np.where( c >= 5 )[0]
# Or np.flatnonzero( c>=5 )

# Index into c, get argmin indices among them, index back to original indices
In [98]: idx = threshold[c[threshold].argmin()]

# Finally extract values off the input arrays
In [99]: a[idx],b[idx],c[idx]
Out[99]: (0.5, 2.0, 5.0)
```